# Flutter Web - white screen / blank page on mobile iOS version of web application

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-web, firebase-hosting

Currently developing a web app with Flutter web. Building, running and accessing the Firebase hosted application works fine when I'm on my laptop or Android device, however when I try to visit the application on a mobile iOS device I get a blank screen. I have tested this with several devices and they all show the same blank page. In order to find the culprit I have tried the following:

- Building and deploying with channels master / dev / beta
- Adding and omitting canvas and/or --release to the build using `flutter build web --web-renderer canvaskit --release`
- Cleaning my project along with deleting all generated code using `flutter clean && find lib -maxdepth 20 -type f \( -name \"*.freezed.dart\" -o  -name \"*.g.dart\" -o  -name \"*.chopper.dart\" \) -delete`
- Changing `<base href="/">` to `<base href="./">` in my index.html
- Updating the first iOS meta tag to `<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">` in my index.html
- Searching StackOverflow and Flutter issues for similar issues with no result
- Cleaning my cache and trying different phones

Edit: Safari on desktop also seems to cause a white screen (!)

My `pubspec.yaml`:

```
name: X
description: X

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 0.1.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter

  # Firebase
  firebase_core: ^1.0.2
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.3
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.1

  # Stacked
  stacked: ^2.0.2

  # Data
  freezed: ^0.14.1+2
  freezed_annotation: ^0.14.1
  json_serializable: ^4.1.0

  # Util
  get: 4.1.1
  intl: ^0.17.0
  get_it: ^6.0.0
  url_strategy: ^0.2.0
  flutter_dotenv: ^4.0.0-nullsafety.0
  logger: ^1.0.0
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.0.0
  flutter_form_builder: ^6.0.0-nullsafety.1

  # Https
  chopper: 4.0.0-nullsafety.0

  # UI
  progress_indicators: ^1.0.0
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  overlay_support: ^1.2.1
  flutter_svg: ^0.21.0+1
  google_fonts: ^2.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  build_runner: ^1.12.2
  stacked_generator: ^0.3.3
  chopper_generator: 4.0.0-nullsafety.0

flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - .env
    - icon/
    - svg/
    - font/

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
flutter_intl:
  enabled: true # Required. Must be set to true to activate the package. Default: false
  class_name: LocalizedStrings # Optional. Sets the name for the generated localization class. Default: S
  main_locale: en # Optional. Sets the main locale used for generating localization files. Provided value should consist of language code and optional script and country codes separated with underscore (e.g. 'en', 'en_GB', 'zh_Hans', 'zh_Hans_CN'). Default: en
  arb_dir: lib/l10n # Optional. Sets the directory of your ARB resource files. Provided value should be a valid path on your system. Default: lib/l10n
  output_dir: lib/generated # Optional. Sets the directory of generated localization files. Provided value should be a valid path on your system. Default: lib/generated
  use_deferred_loading: false # Optional. Must be set to true to generate localization code that is loaded with deferred loading. Default: false
#  localizely: # Optional settings if you use Localizely platform. Read more: https://localizely.com/flutter-localization-workflow
#    project_id: # Get it from the https://app.localizely.com/projects page.
#    branch: # Get it from the “Branches” page on the Localizely platform, in case branching is enabled and you want to use a non-main branch.
#    upload_overwrite: # Set to true if you want to overwrite translations with upload. Default: false
#    upload_as_reviewed: # Set to true if you want to mark uploaded translations as reviewed. Default: false
#    download_empty_as: # Set to empty|main|skip, to configure how empty translations should be exported from the Localizely platform. Default: empty
#    ota_enabled: # Set to true if you want to use Localizely Over-the-air functionality. Default: false
```

My `flutter doctor`:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel dev, 2.2.0-10.1.pre, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H524 darwin-x64, locale
    en-NL)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.55.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    ! Error: iPhone is not connected. Xcode will continue when iPhone is connected.
      (code -13)

• No issues found!
```

My `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base href="./">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
    <meta name="description" content="X">

    <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="dashboard">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

    <title>X</title>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>
<body>
<!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
     application. For more information, see:
     https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
<script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        window.addEventListener('flutter-first-frame', function () {
            navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js?v=107771284');
        });
    }
</script>
<!--Firebase-->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.20.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script>
    var firebaseConfig = {
//
    };
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    firebase.analytics();
</script>
<script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What's causing this problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: While this question is on-topic here, you'll likely get a better response for a problem like this with a [Flutter github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues). Just be sure to include a minimal, reproducible example. This also means including your Dart code in addition to your index.html. Your pubspec.yaml can also likely be omitted.

Comment: Wasn't sure if related to Flutter or maybe some third party plugins that I'm using so I thought I'd try here first along with my pubspec. Will take your advice, thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify your trying to access your Flutter web app from an iOS device? Which browser are you using? I know Safari has some compatibility issues

Comment: Hey Jackson, I have tried chrome as well as safari. Should've mentioned that.

Comment: Hey, did you get any resolution on this?

Comment: I haven't unfortunately, however I think Firebase packages might have something to do with it. I will try and recreate the project copy pasting step by step to find the culprit and keep this thread updated when I get to it.

Comment: Do you have any solution ? @BrianManuputty

Comment: I am also facing this issue with my flutter web app. It works perfectly fine on desktop and Android devices but some of the more recent iPhones, it gives a white screen and the keyboard is inaccessible when you bring focus into the text box

Comment: The project that I was working on got a delayed so I haven't tried to fix this lately. I am starting it again this week so I'll keep you updated if the issue still persists and if I'm able to fix it or at least understand it.

Comment: Any update?? Coz even I have the same issue.. I'm using html-renderer btw.

Answer (score 1):

A similar issue has been [reported](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/77185) where the Flutter web page is blank in Safari. Possible cause of this issue is one of the plugins that's being used. You can isolate the cause of this issue by commenting out the plugins being used.

Another path that you can also try is by upgrading the Flutter version that the Flutter app uses as well as the plugins being used.

Answer (score -1):

the problem maybe, not insertion of `GoogleServise-info.plist` file correctly,

this file needs to be added through Xcode only, copy and paste will won't work,

also you can try Adding internet permissions,

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
   <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
</dict>
```

in info.plist file

then you can also try
`flutter clean` > `flutter pub get` > `flutter run`